# django кастомная модель пользователя

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.
Создал свою модель пользователя. Настроил админку. Все работает кроме
1) кнопки "Добавить пользователя" (в веб админке)
2) не отображаются группы и права ( в коде видно, что добавил как filter_horizontal)
Подскажите плиз в чем проблема? выдает ошибку при нажатии на кнопку добавить: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
модель:

```
class AuthUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have email')
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('User must have username')
    user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
    user.is_active = True
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, validators=[alphanumeric])
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email field', unique=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    # profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', blank=False, default='/static/selfphoto.jpg')
    user_bio = models.TextField()
    perm = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    podr = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dolznost = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = AuthUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '%s %s %s' .format(self.last_name, self.first_name, self.second_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.second_name, self.podr, self.dolznost)
```

формы:

```
class AuthUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = AuthUser
    fields = ('email', 'username')



 def clean_username(self):
        username = self.clean_data['username']
        try:
            AuthUser._default_managet.get(username=username)
        except Authuser.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password do not match.')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class AuthUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label='password', help_text='There is no way too see this password.')

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions', 'perm')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial['password']
```

админка:

```
class AuthUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
form = AuthUserChangeForm
add_form = AuthUserCreationForm

list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',)
list_filter = ('is_superuser',)

fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined', 'user_bio', 'podr', 'dolznost')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'perm')}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_stuff', 'is_superuser', 'perm')
    })
)

search_fields = ('username', 'email')
ordering = ('username',)
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions')
```

трас:

```
Traceback:
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "D:\Python\lib\contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in add_view
  121.                                                extra_context)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1516.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "D:\Python\lib\contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1456.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in get_form
  79.         return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_form
  675.             fields = flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj))
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in flatten_fieldsets
  101.     for name, opts in fieldsets:

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/app/authuser/add/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая проблема решается очень просто: нужно добавить поля `groups` и `user_permissions` в `fieldsets` /`add_fieldsets` туда, где они должны отображаться. Свойство `filter_horizontal` всего лишь указывает на то, что к полям, перчисленным в нём нужно применить этот виджет, но не больше.

<strike>Насчёт кнопки `Добавить пользователя`, к сожалению, совета дать не могу, но, судя по `'NoneType' object is not iterable` похоже, что вы где-то пытаетесь обратиться к полям ещё не созданной модели или что-то в этом духе. Не могли бы дать больше отладочной информации?</strike>

Для `AuthUserCreationForm` и `AuthUserChangeForm` используйте наследование от `forms.ModelForm`, а не `UserCreationForm`.

```
class AuthUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('email', 'username')



    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.clean_data['username']
        try:
            AuthUser._default_managet.get(username=username)
        except Authuser.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password do not match.')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class AuthUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label='password', help_text='There is no way too see this password.')

    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions', 'perm')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial['password']
```

Comment: Вторая проблема решена. Спасибо. По поводу первой: модель и админка выложены в первом посте. Пользователи создаються через шелл без проблем, а в админке - ошибка. ( в главный пост добавил трас

Comment: @FlatOMG обновил ответ, добавил решение первой проблемы, но не факт, что оно сработает. Не могли бы проверить?

Comment: та же ошибка(( 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: ...  кстати редактировать и сохранять пользователя можно без проблем, стопорится на добавлении нового